# How to add a data-delay control function in IB API?

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers

I coded an Interactive Brokers API to get stream data and place orders by signal. It works well. But when I sleep, the connection happened to disconnect. I want to add a data-delay function to restart API after 30 secs data delay.

```
    def ifDataDelay(self):
        print('ifDataDelay monitored')
        while True:
            if int(datetime.now().timestamp()) - self.LastReceivedDataTime >30:
                print('30 sec delay',datetime.fromtimestamp(self.LastReceivedDataTime),datetime.fromtimestamp(int(datetime.now().timestamp())))
                # app.ifNoData=True
                raise EOFError
                break
            time.sleep(1)
            

        return
```

But in main() I don't know how to use thread to concurrent run monitor while data stream come in.If I put app.ifDataDelay() in back of app.run,the app.ifDataDelay() will not run.If I put  t = threading.Thread(target = app.ifDataDelay())
t.start()
t.join()

In front of app.run, then the app.run will not run. I don't know how to code, please help, many thanks.

```
def main():
    print('main() run')
    app=TestApp()
    app.nextOrderId=0
    # app.connect('127.0.0.1',7497,0) # IB TWS
    app.connect('127.0.0.1',4002,0) # IB Gateway
    
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = "EUR"
    contract.secType = "CASH" 
    contract.currency = "USD"
    contract.exchange = "IDEALPRO" 

    #request historical data
    app.reqHistoricalData(1,contract,'','2 D','3 mins','MIDPOINT',0,2,True,[])
    # t = threading.Thread(target = app.ifDataDelay())
    
    # t.start()
    # t.join()
    
    app.run()
    app.ifDataDelay()
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally finished the problem.

Open a new thread to monitor the data delay.
If delayed, first unscripted the req data, then disconnect and check isconnected(). If not, raise except to restart main() again.

It works perfectly.